# Do I need to specify add or attach

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

In the case of needed to add a new row for a 1-1 relationship, do I need to specify Add or Attach? And how do I do it if I need to?

```cs
//one tblContent to one tblContentData
//updating the tblContentData corresponding to a particular id in tblContent

int id = 12345;
tblContent entity = db.tblContents.Where(con => con.id == id)
                      .FirstOrDefault();
if (entity == null)
   throw new Exception("id was bad");

if (entity.tblContentData == null)
   entity.tblContentData = new tblContentData();

//proceed with updating the foreign keyed table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Add` is good for new rows.  `Add` is not good for updates.  In the code you posted, the relationship between the entity and context should be preserved so you need to call:

`db.SaveChanges();`

to preserve any updates.

In cases where the relationship is broken you can update the item with `Entry`:

```
   db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
   db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Would you need to add
`db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;` for a new row, or would Entity Framework take care of that for me?

Comment: @ChristopherStevenson - For a new item you should use `Add`.  When doing CRUD => Create's = Add, Edit's I use Entry.